# Tensorflow 2.0 - Training model issues

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am currently learning how to train a model object detection using google colab and tensorflow 2.0 based on this website link [Link](https://qiita.com/IchiLab/items/fd99bcd92670607f8f9b#tf2%E3%81%A7%E5%AD%A6%E7%BF%92)

During training the model process we received this output in the terminal.

2023-09-21 04:38:08.755884: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:954] layout failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Size of values 0 does not match size of permutation 4 @ fanin shape inEfficientDet-D1/model/stack_0/block_1/drop/dropout/SelectV2-2-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer
^C

Does anyone know what is the actual output? Is this process interrupted or it is something expected?

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider sharing an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help reproducing the problem.